# Conditional Reduce on DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a `DStream[RawWeatherData]` object called `parsedWeatherStream` . Each object in `RawWeatherData` class will look like:

(**"725030:14732",2008,1,1**,1,5.0,-3.3,1020.6,290,4.1,2,0.0,**0.2**,0.0)

Parameters of above object: `(wsid, year, month, day, hour, temperature, dewpoint, pressure, windDirection, windSpeed, skyCondition, oneHourPrecip, sixHourPrecip)`

Objects like this is what I will be getting into the Spark Streaming Context from Kafka.

My end goal is to add up the all the `oneHourPrecip` values for all objects in the `DStream` (highlighted in the object with bold on the right side), with a condition checking whether the bold values on the left `(wsid, year, month, day)` ,when comparing two objects in the stream, are same or not.

For this, I was able to do a map from the parsedStream, taking out only the objects I needed:

```
val newStream = parsedWeatherStream.map { weather =>
    (weather.wsid, weather.year, weather.month, weather.day, weather.oneHourPrecip)
}
```

Now I'm not sure what technique should I be using to sum up all the `oneHourPrecip` values. I have tried to conditionally do a reduce, but that ends up in an error:

```
// ERROR: Type mismatch
val transformedStream = newStream.reduce{(a , b) => {
    if (a._1 == b._1 && a._2 == b._2 && a._3 == b._3 && a._4 == b._4)
        (a._1 , a._2 , a._3 , a._4 , a._5 + b._5)
    else
        None //Would like to do Nothing here, so returning None
}}
```

I have also looked into the `transform` operation, but that also doesn't seem to help my cause.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539141/spark-streaming-group-by-custom-function

Comment: Thanks. That should mostly do my job. Never thought the solution could be this simple. I have been searching for this for ages, and wonder why Google never brought that page up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `newStream` object in my question above, I made a small, but subtle change. I added my keys (those 4 values) inside a parantheses, to represent my `newStream` as a key-value pair. Then all I had to do was a `reduceByKey` on it.

```
val newStream = parsedWeatherStream.map { weather =>
    ((weather.wsid, weather.year, weather.month, weather.day), weather.oneHourPrecip)
}.reduceByKey{(a , b) =>
    a + b
}
```